# Winamp playback log plugin (or option)

Tags: winamp

I need some kind logging plugin that will enable me to collect what was actually played out through winamp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created one myself.  If interested get it here:

http://www.streamsink.com/uploads/WinampPlaybackLogger_v1_0.exe

Comment: no longer there

Answer (score 1):

At first glance the Winamp Orgler<sup>TM</sup> plugin seems to do what you want. From the [download page](http://www.winamp.com/media-player):

> Winamp Orgler<sup>TM</sup> lets you track, chart and share your Winamp listening history

However, from the [plugin page](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/winamp-orgler/221993) itself:

> Each time you listen to a song in your library (not including internet radio), the plug-in sends related metadata associated with that file to Winamp to store in your music profile.

Which means you don't have direct access to the data.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I need RAW log data so I can analyze it through my application.

Comment: @Daniel - I know it doesn't help your immediate problem, but MediaMonkey (http://www.mediamonkey.com) stores the last played date and number of plays per track in it's Access database it uses to store the music library. Does Winamp have a similarly accessible database?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Winamp track title monitor](http://www.djkaty.com/winampgenplugin). On [download](http://www.djkaty.com/download) page there's compiled plugin and also Visual Studio source.

It writes a currently played track into a plain text file. It will always overwrite it so there's just the last track played. If you want to append the track to previously played songs you will have to modify the source. You can compile it using Visual Studio Express 2008.

Comment: From the source, I see that there could be problems with the plugin.  For one, it polls the winamp for current song.  I guess that there must be a way for a plugin to get a message for song start and one for song end.

Comment: Found this when I was searching for a way to save a play list form internet radio. Only changed it a bit so it appends new text when song changes instead of rewriting. I've been running it for some months now without any problems actually.

Answer (score 0):

I am very surprised no one has mentioned Last.FM. I do believe they were the pioneers of this. Originally called Audioscrobbler, they still call the act "Scrobbling".

This provide you with a list of tracks you've played, which is exactly the question being asked here.

I've scrobbled tracks since 2003, ultimately reaching the 1,000,000 track limit the site has. I have to roll to a new account now.

Last.FM has a bunch of other stuff built-up around this, including the ability for it to stream, basically, "The music i have been listening to for the past few weeks", on demand, for free. (But for $$$ on portable devices.)

It's good stuff.